# nasm x86-64, problem with word comparison when exceeding value

Tags: nasm

I have a counter stocked in a word used for a loop, to end my loop I use :

```
cmp       word [counter], nbIter
jge       end
```

But for some reason it only works for `nbIter` lesser than 0x8000.
When exceeding this number it jumps to the end at the first iteration.

I tried using two bytes for the counter and comparing the second one whith 0x80 but it was the same result. I still considered the counter as a word when increasing it, I don't know if it was like not doing any change at all.

Here is my full code :

```
SECTION     .data
message:    db 13, '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '0'

msglen:     equ $-message

compteur:   dw 0

timeval:    ; struct needed to call nanosleep system call
  dq 0      ; seconds, dq means "define quadwords" = integers on 8 bytes
  dq 1000000    ; nanoseconds

SECTION     .text
  GLOBAL    _start

_start:
  jmp       loop

loop:
  call      resetreg
  mov           cx, 10          ; diviseur
  mov       rbx, 7
  mov       ax, [compteur]
offset:
  dec       rbx
  cmp       rbx, 3
  je        offset
  xor       rdx, rdx
  div       cx      ; quotient dans ax, reste dans dx
  add       dl, '0'
  mov       [rbx+message], dl
  cmp       ax, 0
  jg        offset
                ; push les registres qu'on risque de modifier
  call      print
  call      pause
                ; pop les registres qu'on a push pour récup leur valeurs

  inc       word [compteur]
  cmp       word [compteur], 0x7fff
  jge       end
  jmp       loop

end:
  call      skipline
  mov       rax, 60     ; system call for exit
  mov       rdi, 0      ; exit code 0, equiv to xor rdi, rdi
  syscall           ; invoke operating system to exit

pause:
  mov       rax, 35         ; syscall nanosleep for x86_64, see man nanosleep
  mov       rdi, timeval    ; pointing to struct encoding duration of sleep
  mov       rsi, 0          ; null means 2nd parameter not used
  syscall
  ret

print:
  mov       rax, 1      ; system call for write
  mov       rdi, 1      ; file handle 1 is stdout
  mov       rsi, message    ; address of string to output
  mov       rdx, msglen ; number of bytes
  syscall               ; invoke operating system to do the write
  ret

resetreg:
  xor       rax, rax
  xor       rbx, rbx
  xor       rcx, rcx
  xor       rdx, rdx
  ret

skipline:
  mov       word [message+1], 0x0a00
  mov       dword [message+3], 0x00000000
  call      print
  ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jge` is a jump for a signed comparison, you're probably looking for `jae` for unsigned comparison

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I guess the reason it stopped working for 0x8000 is because 0x7fff is the upper bound of a siged integer in a word then ?